# bar3d() of mplot3d renders faces of bars incorrectly from specific viewpoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, rendering, mplot3d

I've made a 3D bar plot in Python with `mplot3d`'s `bar3d()` method. As I either manually or programatically change the viewpoint, sometimes it renders the bars incorrectly.

The values of elevation and azimuth in this specific example are:

```
ax.elev = 40
ax.azim = -120
```

I don't really understand what the `zsort` keyword argument of `bar3d()` is good for - I couldn't find the description in the docs - but anyway I tried all the three possible values (`min`, `average`, `max`), but none of them made it any better. See the examples below respectively.

[image: zsort='min']

[image: zsort='average']

[image: zsort='max']

Any idea what do I miss here?

Comment: This bug seems to be related to the fact that matplotlib is not a real 3d plotting library and rather tries to project your 3d-data to 2d. Unfortunately, the algorithms used are not very sophisticated and produce errors like the ones you observed. I guess you have to use a real 3d-plotting library. Mayavi might be a promising candidate.